# Trouble writing a Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to write a DE and find the general solution for the following description: the rate of change of a substance A at time t is proportional to the inverse of the amount of the substance present at time t.

My solution is as follows:

$dA/dt = k*(1/A)$ for all k in R.

I tried using separation of variables and integration to solve for the general solution:

$ \int A(t) dA = \int k dt $, but this does not make much sense to me.

My other approach was:

$ \int 1/k dA = \int 1/A(t) dt $, which yielded $ 1/k * A(t) = ln(A(t)) + C $ but this does not seem correct.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't correct. $\int \frac{\mathrm dt}{t} = \ln t + C$, but in general $\int \frac{\mathrm dt}{A(t)} \ne \ln(A(t)) + C$.

Your first form was correct, but you got hung up on thinking of $A$ as a function of $t$. $A$ *is* a function of $t$, but it is also, very trivially, a function of $A$, so it is okay to integrate $\int A\mathrm dA = \frac{(A(t))^2}{2} + C$.

Comment: Wow okay I actually did this before posting and thought no way this was right. I was grossly overthinking this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following is correct (using separation of variables):

$$ \int A\ dA = \int k \ dt$$

$$ \frac{A^2}{2} = kt + C$$

where $C$ is a constant of integration.